# Merge columns of a dataframe into a list after merging by the first column

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
   'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
   'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
   'C' : np.random.randn(8), 'D' : np.random.randn(8)})
```

which creates:

```
     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one -0.151044  2.235048
1  bar    one -0.732017  0.415994
2  foo    two -1.203263 -1.178483
3  bar  three  0.329306  0.356476
4  foo    two  0.512176 -2.640831
5  bar    two -0.997254  0.504314
6  foo    one  0.434732  0.751182
7  foo  three -0.558386 -1.563932
```

Can one group by either by A or B, which would give values of C and D as list in a new dataframe? the way group_concat works in mysql.

```
grouped = df.groupby('A').apply(WhatFunctionCanIUse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list inside a DataFrame is not usually convenient to use. There is probably a more natural way of doing whatever you're ultimately trying to do. If you elaborate, maybe someone will suggest a more idiomatic solution.

But, to answer your question, you can apply `list`.

```
In [26]: df.groupby('A').C.apply(list)
Out[26]: 
A
bar                     [-0.732017, 0.329306, -0.997254]
foo    [-0.151044, -1.203263, 0.512176, 0.434732, -0....
dtype: object
```

Comment: well, what I am trying to do is to have all my results ready out of mysql, and then do different types of merging to get my plots.
e.g. say you have results of chemical vs animal vs effect. I want to see different plots of chemical vs effect merged by animal on one graph.

Comment: If you can get your "merged" data into columns of a DataFrame, the ``.plot()`` will show each column as a separate line on the same plot. If you need more help with said merging, I suggest you open a new question with a working example with a sample of the chemical, animal, effect data you're talking about.